# Grails Scaffolding is not storing reference for given domain structure

Tags: java, grails, groovy

**Usecase:** Player may have award or may not have. If player never had any award then Award will be null, *( **1.** Is there any other way to do this.. without null.. I don't feel its good idea)*
I am  generating scaffold for following domain structure.

```
class Player {
    String name
    Award recentAward
    static constraints = {
        recentAward(nullable:true)
    }
}

class Award {
    String awardName
    int reputation
    Player bloodBag
    static belongsTo=Player
    static constraints = {
    }
}
```

When I create Player.. I do not provide Award.. 
when I create Award.. Selecting Player is compulsory.. from drop-down. 
Now, After creating few Players, we can create Award with appropriate Player selection. But when opened in list or show view. Player is blank, I mean it is null, not set when Award was created.

In **save()** of **AwardController** statement **println(awardInstance.player);** prints proper value. and I also did **awardInstance.player.save()** after **println** statement, but in vain.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out the documentation on the [hasOne](http://grails.org/doc/latest/ref/Domain%20Classes/hasOne.html) relationship that was added in grails 1.2 (just released).

It allows you to define the Player/Award relationship where the Award would then have the foreign key to the player (if it exists).